Smoothness of a cylinder
I´m trying to check the smoothness property of a cylinder $D:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2\leq 1, z\in [0, H]\}$, but I´m having a problem understanding the definition of Lipschitz continuous boundary (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_domain).
In Surface of a cylinder is a differentiable manifold it was shown that the unbounded cylinder is a differentiable manifold. The mappings from there (restricted to $z\in (0, H)$) can be used as mappings on the "side" of the cylinder. And it´s not hard to find differentiable mappings for the "top" and "bottom" parts (without the circular 1D-boundary), since these are flat surfaces $x^2+y^2<1$ and $z\in \{0,H\}$.
My main issue is to find a Lipschitz mapping for the boundary parts at $x^2+y^2=1$ and
$z\in \{0, H\}$. Can anybody help?

Have you done the simpler example of a square in the plane?

After following Ted's good suggestion, you may find spherical coordinates help with handling the boundary of the cylinder along the corners.
